# Can we skip a argument in the (%*)?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, command-line-arguments, arguments

How can I skip an argument like `%~1` in the `%*`?

```
@echo off
title  
cls
:loop
set /p command=
call :command %command%
goto :loop
:command
if "%~1"=="title"(
  %~1 %*
)
goto :eof
```

I'm trying to create my own cmd in there.

But I have a problem: when I try to set my cmd's window title the output is:

```
title test title
```

Or when I create an `echo` command, the output is:

```
echo test echo command
```

That is, the command itself is also inside the output.

Can we skip `%~1` in the `%*`?

Or should I use any other command?

Comment: `%*` represents **all** args no exceptions, you could use `shift` to remove an arg from the numbered list and though gain access to former agrs 10 and up.

Comment: @LotPings example please :)

Comment: read the help `shift /?` or [online](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)

Comment: @LotPings nope, it isn't skipping "%~1" argument while i'm using "%*".

Comment: Read the help and my 1st comment  again.

Comment: IMO, an optimal solution is there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/761658/1421036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If splitting a delimited string into tokens is the objective, including, as here, separating the first delimited token from the remainder of the string, then FOR /F is much more flexible and useful.

```
@echo off
title  
cls
:loop
set /p command=
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ("%command%") do if /I "%%~A"=="title" %%A %%B
goto :loop
```

Comment: yep, this is what i'm exactly want!

Comment: this will fail if [any arguments [are quoted and] contain spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702448/1421036)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct batch line interpretion as follows:

```
@echo off
title  
cls
:loop
set /p command=
call :command_%command%
goto :loop


:command_title
title %*
exit /b
```

E. g. if user types "`title this is the name of the window`" batch executes following: `call :command_title this is the name of the window`. Inside of `:command_title` the %* just holds the extra arguments, so %1 doesn't exist in that sense.